# VS Code terminal not running at all

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, terminal, path

Every time I try to run python file in vs code terminal shows me that white line without any respond , I checked path option when installed python and reinstalled vs code but nothing worked

[image]

Comment: Just checking, do you have the python extension installed? (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)

Comment: @Fastnlight yes its installed

Comment: Instead of pressing run, right click the file and select `Python: Run Python File in Terminal`. See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

since you have not given any details about which system you're running, neither if this is a newly occurring problem (i.e. you've used the VSc terminal before without issues).
my guess is that you're running a version that is not compatible with your pc.
(might want to reinstall VS code, the 64bit version)

Check out this page :
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/troubleshoot-terminal-launch#_the-terminal-not-working-when-running-the-32bit-windows-client-on-64bit-windows

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try to use cmd. And click **Run Python File**

[image]

Comment: not working :((

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be from your file name.. It appears you wrongly named your python file as "hi.py.py" instead of "hi.py". Try renaming your file and run the code again.